# Change batch of hyperlinks automatically

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I tried to change many hyperlinks, which are located in specific cells. For example in F21:F30 the hyperlinks are located. F21 contains the correct hyperlink with the folder path ending in ..\m%20(70). The cell G21 contains the text "70 General". Now G22 contains the text "71 Electric installation". Thus I want the hyperlink of F22 to end with ..\m%20(71). Now G23 contains the text "73 Phone installation", so naturally I wan the hyperlink of F23 to end with ..\m%20(73). In conclusion there is a sequence in column G which is part of the hyperlink path in column F.

The above example also applies to H21:H30 and I21:I30 and to F34:F43 and G34:G43 and many more cells in the same sheet (see picture).

[image: Screenshot of hyperlink sheet]

How can I change all of the hyperlinks automatically?

The function

```
=HYPERLINK
```

is I think not an option, because the number is in the same cell as the text.

I also tried to include this solution [Use VBA to hyperlink based on cell text](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/use-vba-to-hyperlink-based-on-cell-text.616426/)

Comment: The linked MrExcel post is broadly along the right lines.  Show what you tried and tell us what went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use the function Hyperlink
if the F column write:

```
=HYPERLINK("..\m%20(" & LEFT(G21,INSTR(G21, " ") - 1) & ")")
```

So we look for the first space, get all chars before that and use this in the HYPERLINK

Comment: I tried your solution and replaced the =INSTR with =SEARCH. =HYPERLINK("..\m (70)(" & LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" ", B2) - 1) & ")"). This resulted in the following hyperlink: ..\m (70)(71). So instead of replacing the 70 by 71 it added the 71 to the hyperlink.

Comment: I think you or I misunderstand. If you put in column F21 the code above, your link 70 should work. If you copy this code to F22 and replace G21 with G22 (what excel is doing automatically when copying), the link will work for 71. Why you want to use Search?

Comment: I tried the following formula =HYPERLINK("\\ad.rws.nl\p-dfs01\project\wnn\Areaal_Nat_Startpagina\Pompen\P (10)\70\m "&"("&LEFT(G23;SEARCH(" "; G23) - 1) & ")"; F21). This will give me the correct hyperlink to the correct folder, however I want to reference the hyperlink of F21 and replace the last part which is (70) with (71). I tried this =HYPERLINK(F21&"("&LEFT(G23;SEARCH(" "; G23) - 1) & ")"; F21), but that wouldn't work.

Comment: For sure this is not working. Why you want to use a kind of Master URL? If this is needed first of all, put it in F1 and reference as F$1. Second, leave out any numbers and make it the master:"\\ad.rws.nl\p-dfs01\project\wnn\Areaal_Nat_Startpagina\Pompen\P (10)\". Then in Hyperlink add the number